# C# - Call Method in Base Class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, .net-4.0, polymorphism

I have 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite + " from B"); }
}
```

In my code I do the following:

```
B writeClass = new B();
writeClass.WriteLine("Output"); // I expect to see 'Output from B'
A otherClass = (A)writeClass;
otherClass.WriteLine("Output"); // I expect to see just 'Output'
```

I presumed this would work because of [polymorphism.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

However, it always writes 'Output from B' every time. Is there anyway to get this to work the way I want it to?

**EDIT** Fixing code example.

Comment: its `public void WriteLine` not `public void Write`

Comment: should the method in `A` be `WriteLine` and **not** `Write`?

Comment: New just hides the base implementation so you can still call the base implementation by explicitly calling the method from the base

Comment: The fixed code example works fine for me in LINQPad. Output: `Output from B
Output`

Comment: The code you posted *does* have the output that you expect on my machine. If it does not have this output on your machine then you have discovered a bug in the compiler; please post the exact version number of the compiler you're using so that I can try to reproduce it in that version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you "hide" a method from the base class using NEW you are just hiding it, thats it. It's still called when you explicitily call the base class implementation.

A doesnt contain WriteLine so you need to fix that. When I fixed it I got

```
Output from B
Output


namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B writeClass = new B(); 
            writeClass.WriteLine("Output"); // I expect to see 'Output from B' 
            A otherClass = (A)writeClass; 
            otherClass.WriteLine("Output"); // I expect to see just 'Output' 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite); }
    }
    public class B : A
    {
        public new void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite + " from B"); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method on class A is Write, not WriteLine. Change it to the same name and it will work as you expect. I just tried it and get:

```
Output from B
Output
```

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) explains this quite well. (This is the newer version of the original poster's link.) The page shows examples where a derived class overrides a virtual member and where new members hide base class members.

There appears to be some confusion over the new modifier. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx):

> Although you can hide members without the use of the new modifier, the
>   result is a warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, it
>   suppresses this warning and documents the fact that the derived
>   version is intended as a replacement.

Note that the hidden member does not need to be virtual.

**Best practices:**

- Strongly prefer overriding to hiding. Polymorphic calls are idiomatic in OO languages.
- If you intend to hide a member, **always** use the new modifier.
- Never release code with compiler warnings.
- If *every* developer on your team agrees that a compiler warning cannot be fixed, suppress it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new` keyword when you override the method in class `B`. And declare the method in `A` as `virtual`.

Comment: new is basically to avoid a compiler warning. It makes no difference to the execution.

Comment: What if he cant set the method to virtual as in it isn't his base class to modify. Then what? He has to use New

Comment: @DustinDavis - He doesn't **have** to use new; he **should** use new. Try it.

Comment: @TrueWill Yes, I know but that isn't acceptable (at least for my team). I require the use of New to make it clear that this is what we were intending.

Comment: @DustinDavis - We agree on that. :) My point was that the keyword does not affect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' keyword is making B's implementation of WriteLine overwrite A's implementation.

Don't accept this as an answer, but in my experience, it's almost always a mistake to use the 'new' keyword in this fashion. It's less readable and muddy's the clarity of your code.

Comment: I agree about avoiding the new keyword whenever possible, but its presence isn't overwriting the implementation. It's basically suppressing a compiler warning. Redeclaring the method without using virtual/override is what's overwriting the implementation, but in a non-polymorphic manner (as @DustinDavis demonstrates).

Comment: Yup, I was trying to simplify the behavior somewhat. But I think the fact that two experienced developers have have doubts about the best way to explain its behavior just goes to show how dangerous it actually is!

Answer (score 0):

Your class A has a Write function instead of WriteLine

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void WriteLine(string toWrite) { Console.WriteLine(toWrite + " from B"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I guess you wanted to name the methods both "WriteLine" but the one in class A is only named "Write". And second: yes you inherit B from A but the object will still be of type "B" so now I don't think what you want is possible.